# Writing images to folder (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have WebAPI project and need to get image from mobile app and write it to folder.

Here is my code

```
 public class ImageController : ApiController
{
    public bool SaveImage(string ImgStr, string ImgName)
    {
        String path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Image"); //Path

        //Check if directory exist
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path); //Create directory if it doesn't exist
        }

        string imageName = ImgName + ".jpg";

        //set the image path
        string imgPath = Path.Combine(path, imageName);

        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ImgStr);

        File.WriteAllBytes(imgPath, imageBytes);

        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is My url that I see in API tab

`http://localhost:55341/api/Image?ImgStr={ImgStr}&ImgName={ImgName}`

I send two parameters in request. ImgStr with base 64 sting and ImgName with static name - Test.

But I have this

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. ","ExceptionType":"System.FormatException","StackTrace":"   at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)\r\n   at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)\r\n   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)\r\n   at trackingappbackend.Controllers.ImageController.SaveImage(String ImgStr, String ImgName) in C:\Users\nemes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\trackingappbackend\trackingappbackend\Controllers\ImageController.cs:line 29\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

But I send valid base64 string.

Where can be problem?

Comment: I wouldnt pass an image as a url parameter, there is a limit on the size dependent on the browser.  Much better to use a post parameter, it will also get you around the encoding issue.  Try that and see if you get a better result

Answer (score 0):

Base64 string can contain the "+", "=" and "/" which isn't valid characters in querystring. I think you shouldn't pass Image as base64 in querystring. Try use body of post/put.

In your case, exception says:

> more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned, one problem is the interference between base64 characters and URL separators, which I suspect to be the culprit here. That can be solved with URL-Encoding.

The next problem you'll probably run into is the limited length an URL can have.

The standard way to do this in HTTP is to PUT/POST the image in the message body as bytes, with a proper ContentType of "image/jpeg", so no base64 encoding at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can the following peace of code that is to convert your base64tsring to an image.

```
 byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

    Image image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }

    image.Save(fullOutputPath+imagename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```